# Shopware 6 product tags as product listing

Tags: php, symfony, shopware, shopware6

Tags in shopware are for internal use only but we need them to be more advanced. Tag should have it's own page, just like product but contain product listing and translatable text field for SEO purposes, tag name should be translatable as well.

For sure I have to create custom storefront routing, page and templates, create my own ProductTag entity, create page in administration for managing tags.

Questions:

1. How to configure routing that in url will be '/tag/cups/' instead '/tag/{uudi}'
2. How to create administration part for managing tags? I know I have to create module but what exactly should it contain? Is there something else I should create?
3. How to make my tag's name in administration translatable?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use whatever placeholder you like, not necessarily only for UUIDs. Just choose a placeholder name, set a requirement (if you only want to allow certain characters) and use the name of the tag in a criteria or in any way you need it:

```php
/**
 * @Route("/tag/{name}", name="frontend.my.route", methods={"GET"}, requirements={"name"="[a-zA-Z-]+"})
 */
public function listing(Request $request, Context $context, string $name): Response
```

2. Since version `6.4.11.0` Shopware already comes with a [tag administration](https://docs.shopware.com/en/shopware-6-en/settings/tags)
3. You could [extend the definition of `tag`](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-complex-data-to-existing-entities) and [add translatable fields on a database level](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/framework/data-handling/add-data-translations). This isn't quite so trivial though and you'd also need a way to provide these translations, possibly extending the aforementioned tag administration. It might be easier to translate the technical name of a tag in the storefront template:

```
{{ ('my.custom.translations.tags.' ~ tag.name)|trans }}
```

The corresponding json for translations for this example:

```json
{
  "my": {
    "custom": {
      "translations": {
        "tags": {
          "technical-tag-name": "Actual readable and translated name"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: even if built-in Tags were used I still need to extend Entity to add string field for SEO and extend administration so I have input for that text. 

As for translatable Tag name I thought to make it like category name so changing language at the top of page I can input name for another language but I guess it would be hard to do with existing Tag Entity. Depends on client if there will be more languages in store